# Regex: Regular expression to pick the nth parameter of the response

Tags: c++, regex

Consider the example below:

```
AT+CEREG?
+CEREG: "4s",123,"7021","28","8B7200B",8,,,"00000010","10110100"
```

The desired response would be to pick `n`

```
n=1  => "4s"
n=2  => 123
n=8  => 
n=10 => 10110100
```

---

**In my case**, I am enquiring some details from an LTE modem and above is the type of response I receive.

[I have created this regex](https://regex101.com/r/2PpRHm/1) which captures the `(n+1)`th member under `group 2` including the last member, however, I can't seem to work out how to pick the 1st parameter in the approach I have taken.

```
(?:([^,]*,)){5}([^,].*?(?=,|$))?
```

Could you suggest an alternative method or complete/correct mine?

Comment: Try [`:\s*(?:[^,]*,){min}([^,]*)`](https://regex101.com/r/2PpRHm/2) where `min` is the `n-1` position. If it is PCRE compatible, use [`:\s*(?:[^,]*,){0}(?|"([^,]*)"|([^,\s]+))`](https://regex101.com/r/2PpRHm/3) to exclude double quotes.

Comment: My environment is C/C++ however mr. correction removed my tags not knowing different environments could respond differently to Regexes.

Comment: Ok, have you got any code to share? It would greatly simplify debugging and will allow us to help you better and quicker. Or, you will have answers like the one wp78de posted.

Comment: @wiktor, your suggestion works perfectly fine. Please cook up an answer from it and I'll mark it as an answer. By the way, great job.

Comment: I reverted C++ tag since every question with regex tag must have the appropriate language tag, and you indicated you are using C++. I provided 2 solutions, one for any regex library, and another for Boost (or PCRE/PCRE2 if you want).

Comment: @eyllanesc please leave a comment when you remove all language tags (even when it is justified) from a regex question next time. Probably not everybody understands what's the problem.

Comment: @Mehrad It is not good to abuse tags, C and C ++ are very linked but different languages, each one handles the data in a different way, that is easy to see for example from the fact of opening files or printing text, so I recommend not use both, in similar cases I delete both tags if the user does not mention the preference for some or some code where I can discern.

Comment: @eyllanesc it's all good. This was just an invitation to make things more transparent and help others to succeed. A simple comment can help a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may start matching from `:` (or `+CEREG:` if it is a static piece of text) and use

```
:\s*(?:[^,]*,){min}([^,]*)
```

where `min` is the `n-1` position of the expected value.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2PpRHm/2). This solution is **`std::regex`** compatible.

**Details**

- `:` - a colon
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?:[^,]*,){min}` - `min` occurrences of any 0+ chars other than `,` followed with `,`
- `([^,]*)` - Capturing group 1: 0+ chars other than `,`.

A **`boost::regex`** solution might look neater since you may easily capture substrings inside double quotes or substrings consisting of chars other than whitespace and commas using a [*branch reset group*](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html#boost_regex.syntax.perl_syntax.branch_reset):

```
:\s*(?:[^,]*,){0}(?|"([^"]*)"|([^,\s]+))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2PpRHm/4)

**Details**

- `:\s*(?:[^,]*,){min}` - same as in the first pattern
- `(?|` - start of a branch reset group where each alternative branch shares the same IDs:

  - `"([^"]*)"` - a `"`, then Group 1 holding any 0+ chars other than `"` and then a `"` is just matched
  - `|` - or
  - `([^,\s]+))` - (still Group 1): one or more chars other than whitespace and `,`.